# String cannot be added to List using Object in Java

Tags: java, arrays, object

I am working on a JSF based Web Application where I read contents from a file(dumpfile) and then parse it using a logic and keep adding it to a list using an object and also set a string using the object. But I keep getting this error. I am confused where I am wrong. I am a beginner so can anyone be kind enough to help me?

```
List<DumpController> FinalDumpNotes;
public List<DumpController> initializeDumpNotes()
throws SocketException, IOException {
PostProcessedDump postProcessedDump = (PostProcessedDump) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getSessionMap().get("postProcessedDump");
List<DumpController> FinalNotes = new ArrayList<>();
if (postProcessedDump.getDumpNotes() == null) {
dumpNotes = new DumpNotes();
}
DumpListController dlcon = (DumpListController) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getSessionMap().get("dumpListController");
DumpInfo dumpinfo = dlcon.getSelectedDumpInfo();
String fileName = dumpinfo.getDate() + dumpinfo.getTime() + dumpinfo.getSeqNo() + dumpinfo.getType() + dumpinfo.getTape() + dumpinfo.getDescription() + ".txt";
if (checkFileExistsInWin(fileName)) {
postProcessedDump.setDumpnotescontent(getFileContentsFromWin(fileName));
String consolidateDumpnotes = getFileContentsFromWin(fileName);
String lines[];
String content = "";
lines = consolidateDumpnotes.split("\\r?\\n");
List<String> finallines = new ArrayList<>();
int k = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < lines.length; i++) {
if (!lines[i].equalsIgnoreCase("")) {
finallines.add(lines[i]);
k++;
}
}
for (int j = 0; j < finallines.size(); j++) {
if (finallines.get(j).startsWith("---------------------SAVED BY")) {
PostProcessedDump dump = new PostProcessedDump();
dump.setDumpMessage(content);
content = "";
FinalDumpNotes.add(dump);
} else {
content = content + finallines.get(j);
}
}
}
FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getSessionMap().put("postProcessedDump", postProcessedDump);
return FinalDumpNotes;
}
```

I get the following error:
[image]

Comment: because they are not from same type!your `FinalDumpNotes` is a collection of `DumpController` and your `dump` is `PostProcessedDump`.

Comment: Did you actually take a picture of your monitor to provide that screenshot? That kinda cheers me up :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to add instances of type `PostProcessedDump` to your `List` you should change it's type. Also, don't forget to initialize it. Something like,

```
List<PostProcessedDump> FinalDumpNotes = new ArrayList<>();
```

Also, Java naming convention is to start variable names with a lower case letter. `FinalDumpNotes` looks like a class, I would suggest something like

```
 List<PostProcessedDump> processedList = new ArrayList<>();
```

Answer (score 1):

Problems with your code:

```
List<DumpController> FinalDumpNotes;
```

You declare `FinalDumpNotes` to be a `List` of `DumpController` objects, but you never initialize it.  In addition, your IDE is barfing on the following line of code:

```
FinalDumpNotes.add(dump);
```

because you are attempting to add a `PostProcessedDump` object to the `List` instead of a `DumpController` object.

For starters, you need to initialize your list like this:

```
List<DumpController> finalDumpNotes = new ArrayList<DumpController>();
```

Notice that I have made the variable name beginning with lower case, which is the convention (upper case is normally reserved for classes and interfaces).

I will leave it to you as a homework assignment to sort out the correct usage of this `List`.

Comment: I replaced my line with yours and still same error persists

Comment: Your code is in a mess.  The answers given here explain the error you were seeing in your IDE.